# UILabel not getting contents immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension to get my TableViewCells to automagically resize to the content. If I have multiple lines of text in the first cell, it takes the correct height but only displays the first line of content until I scroll down and back up.

The label is configured in the storyboard with:

[image][image]

Initial Load:[image]

After scrolling:[image]

ViewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.tableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 250
    self.tableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    ProgressHUD.show("Loading...", interaction: false)
    let API = postAPI()
    API.getNew() {
        (result: [Post]?) in
        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
        if let ps = result {
            if self.posts.count != ps.count {
                self.posts.removeAll()
                self.posts.appendContentsOf(ps)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            ProgressHUD.showError("There was a problem getting new posts")
        }
    }
}
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OMCFeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OMCFeedTableViewCell
    let p = posts[indexPath.row]

    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    let data = p.content!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let content = try! JSON(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers))

    if let image = content["image"].string {
        let uploads = uploadAPI()
        uploads.tryGetImage(image) {
            (result: UIImage?) in

            if let i = result {
                cell.postImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                cell.postImage.image = i
            }
        }
    }

    cell.postText.text = ""
    if let text = content["text"].string {
        cell.postText.text = text
    }

    return cell
}
```

Constraints on vote bar:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?  How is the label configured in your Storyboard?

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the relevant code and configuration options

Comment: Think they wanted to see the constraints.

Comment: @beyowulf added those as well.

Comment: What's postImage? And what are it's constraints?

Comment: postImage is an UIImageView that can optionally contain an image. It's constrained to the top margin

Comment: Does this happen only in cells that don't contain an image?

Comment: It happens only in the first cells that are visible on load if and only if those cells doesn't have an image

Comment: Erik, you have your bottom spacing set to a 'view'. Can you check if this 'view' too has a proper bottom spacing constraint with the superview?

Comment: @Shripada yes this is the view that contains the voting buttons. All my constraint indicators are blue in the Storyboard designer

Comment: OK, have you set proper bottom spacing to this view that contains your buttons?

Comment: @Shripada Yes. Any ideas? It fixes itself after I scroll up/down.

Comment: Can you please show the constraints of this view also?

Comment: @Shripada I added that as well. Anything jump out at you?

Comment: @Paulw11 I also added my code for ViewDidAppear

Comment: @ErikJohnson, I am afraid your 'self.tableView.reloadData()' inside the callback in that API.getNew ends up running in a secondary thread!. Can you ensure it runs in main thread?

Comment: @Shripada could you show me how would I make sure of that? I'm relatively new to iOS and very new to Swift.

Comment: @ErikJohnson I have posted as answer that  runs UI updates within the callback in main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ensure your UI updates happen in main thread. I am suspecting your API.getNew() call seems to be asynchronous and potentially the block is called back in a secondary thread? (I am just speculating it). To ensure the UI update happens in main thread. Do this change to  the code -

```
API.getNew() {
    (result: [Post]?) in
    //Ensure to run UI updates in main thread. The ProgressHUD.dismiss(),  
    //self.tableView.reloadData() must be run in main thread..
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        if let ps = result {
            ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            if self.posts.count != ps.count {
                self.posts.removeAll()
                self.posts.appendContentsOf(ps)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            ProgressHUD.showError("There was a problem getting new posts")
        }
    })
}
```

Similarly look out for this kind of pattens in your code and ensure you don't run UI updates from a secondary thread.

Comment: That fixed the code in the simulator but not on the hardware iPhone. Strange! Note that my sim is on iOS 9 and my iPhone is on iOS 8.

Comment: I ended up finding [this link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html#comment-1992126862) that told me to add cell.layoutIfNeeded() before returning from cellForRowAtIndexPath. That finally fixed it on iOS 8!