# How to resize a UIImageView and force relayout of the parent UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have custom TableViewCells that have UITableViewAutomaticDimension. When I load an image into the cell, it's almost always much too tall for the image, and I end up with large white bars above and below the image. What I am attempting to do is resize the UIImageView to be the same size as the image, but nothing will work.

I also tried creating a new UIImageView and setting that up, but `UIImageView.init(frame: CGRectMake(...) )` returns `nil` for some reason. My Google-fu is failing me on this one.

My code for (attempting) to resize the imageView and parent cell: (note that `i` is my new image and `cell.postImage` is an `IBOutlet` of type `UIImageView!`)

```
let oFrame = cell.postImage.frame
let width = oFrame.width
let height = (i.size.height / i.size.width) * width
cell.postImage.frame = CGRectMake(oFrame.origin.x, oFrame.origin.y, width, height)
cell.postImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
cell.postImage.image = i
cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: What constraints do you have on postImage? In general, it is not advisable to set a frame when you're using auto layout. Rather it is better to set the constraints themselves.

Comment: @beyowulf I have the same constraints as in [my question from last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794042/uilabel-not-getting-contents-immediately) - you can observe the bars above the top edge of the image at the bottom of my screenshots. Basically it is constrained with the top to the superview and the bottom to the content label.

Comment: What is determining the height of the cell, padding + image height+padding+label height+padding?

Comment: @beyowulf Yes that is correct. If there is no image the UIImageView takes up 0 space, as it should.

Comment: Does it have a set aspect ratio or a set width?

Comment: @beyowulf No, the UIImageView has a default width of 288 and a default height of 150, but it is only constrained by margins, not width or aspect ratio

Comment: I also tried increasing the Content Hugging Priority from 250 to 800, but that didn't change anything

Comment: What happens when you change the contentMode?

Comment: @beyowulf changing it to .TopLeft causes the image to fill the available vertical space, but only approximately the left half is displayed

Comment: The manual states for .ScaleAspectFit: "The option to scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent." The thing is, I **don't want** there to be any remaining area.

Comment: Then don't you want .ScaleAspectFill? Or change your horizontal constraints (i.e. leading and trailing) to greater than or equal.

Comment: I also don't want any of my image to be cropped off. It's almost as though I need to resize my image _before_ putting it into the UIImageView... But that just feels dirty, given that I already have functions to scale and retain aspect ratio, I just want to set the height of the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width constraint for postImage. Create an IBOutlet for the height constraint of postImage. Then in say something like:

```
let oFrame = cell.postImage.frame
let width = oFrame.width
let height = (i.size.height / i.size.width) * width
cell.postImageHeightConstraint.constant = height
```

And it looks like you want the image center so align center x.

Comment: I now get an error message about breaking constraints, but it works! Should I post a new question or do you have any ideas? See http://pastebin.com/4Tg8rJj7

Comment: I think you need to set the image view's height priority to 999, but without seeing it I can't be sure.

Comment: That fixed everything. Thanks for the help!